# What exactly are 'discourse linkers'?

Tags: grammar, terminology

I read an English chapter in my school book and then as I was reading the stuff given after the chapter, I read this topic called 'Noticing discourse linkers and signallers' (I have attached the picture of the page I read).

I was able to understand what 'signallers' are but I was not able to even get a clue of what 'linkers' are. I did search it on the internet but I couldn't find a simple and understandable source. So, can anybody please explain this topic to me in as simple words and language as possible?

I will highly appreciate your efforts! :)

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Comment: It is a bit of relatively recent academic jargon describing how certain words and phrases help a discourse (conversation) cohere in the minds of the people having the discourse by referring back to previous chunks of that discourse. Signallers (or segues) indicate a change of topic.  All human languages have such features; they are not limited to English.

Comment: Thanks, Tromano! Can you tell me one thing though, why have you referred them as jargon?

Comment: Your explanation really helped me to understand the topic :)

Comment: Sorry, unclear antecedent with "it"!  **discourse markers** is jargon.

Comment: Why is it jargon? Are they newly induced in modern grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tᴚoɯɐuo indicated in the comments section of your question, [discourse means conversation](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discourse), therefore **discourse linkers** link conversations.  They can be conjunctions in some respects, but in the sense of discourse/conversation linkers, they are normally phrases which link the conversations together.

Some examples were given in the text you provided in the image.

> Talking about novels, ...

would be a discourse linker when the last thing being said was talking about novels.

Comment: Ok, so what I understood is that Linkers are words or phrases that we use while talking, that denote the topic/thing we are talking about. Thanks, Chris, your explanation really helped :)